# how to use triggers and implement them in dbeaver?

Tags: sql, mysql, dbeaver

I've created my trigger for Sql database but how its gonna work ?

````
```
SQL
```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteTransaction
ON Transaction
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TransactionLog (TableName, Action, Timestamp)
    VALUES ('Transaction', 'DELETE', GETDATE())
END; //
DELIMITER ;
````

I want this trigger runs when some of data is gets deleted from transaction table.

Comment: a trigger is executed by the dbms - not dbeaver - and triggers are attached to tables/columns not to "any table for any deletion". If you want to log deletions from tables, you will need to **create a separate trigger for each table** that you are monitoring

Comment: #1. Study [CREATE TRIGGER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html). The action must precede the table name. AS is not used. FOR EACH ROW needed. #2. `Timestamp` is a keyword and must be quoted with backticks. #3. If `Timestamp` column is always assigned with current date during INSERT then set according DEFAULT value to it and does not mention it in INSERT query at all. #4. Each statement in stored object creation code must be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteTransaction
AFTER DELETE ON Transaction
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO TransactionLog (TableName, Action, `Timestamp`)
    VALUES ('Transaction', 'DELETE', GETDATE());
```

Single-statement trigger creation does not need in both BEGIN-END and DELIMITER reassign.